# Finding length of int type in C

Tags: c

I am trying to find an integer type length in C. Does anyone have a quick algorithm to check the length of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question says "in C", why is this tagged `c#` and `objective-c`?

Comment: @Ben I thought someone might be generous to know from those fields as well.

Comment: Re c# (now-removed tags) the answer is simple: 4 bytes, 32 bits. Always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
sizeof (int)
```

If you want it measured in bits, try

```
#include <limits.h>
(CHAR_BIT * sizeof (int))
```

Comment: Note that this will give you the `int`'s length in chars or bits occupied in memory, but strictly speaking it will not give you the “length” in terms of what values it can represent. For that, use `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` from `limits.h`.

Comment: @Arkku: That's the weirdest usage of "length" I've ever seen.

Comment: @Arkku : you are wrong, the length means the number of bytes not the limits.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm guessing because it's a Thursday :)  Upvote for including bits as well as bytes from me.

Comment: @eharvest The OP did not specify the meaning, and considering the oddities in the question (like asking for an algorithm to determine the length, C# in original tags) I wanted to mention this _possible_ (admittedly weird), e.g., to avoid the OP using the length in bits to make assumptions about the range of values.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree, that's why I put “length” in quotes. (For what it's worth I don't disagree with your answer, nor did I downvote it.)

Comment: @Arkku : ok.      upvote for thursday :D. just joke. i upvote for right answer. i do not want any admin to blame me.

Answer (score 3):

Just use **[sizeof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof)** operator, you don't need any algorithm.

```
sizeof(int);
```